# mark "***" at the end of every 12 words

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, cpu-word

There is a text.

text = """Among domestic cats, males are more likely to fight than females. Among feral cats, the most common reason for cat fighting is competition between two males to mate with a female. In such cases, most fights are won by the heavier male. Another common reason for fighting in domestic cats is the difficulty of establishing territories within a small home. Female cats also fight over territory or to defend their kittens."""

How to implement this function (mark "***" every 12 words), please tell me in python 3?

"""
Among domestic cats, males are more likely to fight than females. Among***

feral cats, the most common reason for cat fighting is competition between***

next ...***
"""

Comment: Do you want the first '***' after the first word or the 12th?

Comment: so that the whole sentence + ending *** \n
(Among domestic cats, males are more likely to fight than females. Among ***)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we break the text into individual words using `str.split()`, we can then iterate through every 12 words by setting the step of range to be 12, adding "***" where appropriate and rejoining the words with a space.

```
words = text.split()
for i in range(0, len(words), 12): # step by 12
    words[i] += "***"
new_text = " ".join(words)
```

NOTE: this will mark the 0th word with "***", use `range(11, len(words), 12):` to start with 12th word

Comment: `for i in range(11,len(words),12):` will not mark the first :)

Comment: Nope it will not, but it will mark the 13th not 12th.

Comment: ups sorry, fixed

Comment: My guess is the author is looking for `for i in range(11, len(words), 12):`

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

text = "Create your own function that takes in a sentence and mark every 12th word with ***"

```
mark = " ".join(["{}***".format(word) 
        for idx, word in enumerate(text.split()) 
        if idx % 12 == 0])
print(mark)
```

The main point here is to use the enumerate() function and the modulo operator (%).

Comment: very interesting, but only the endings of words are published, and the whole sentence + ***           (Among*** feral*** two*** are***  ...) = (
  Among domestic cats, males are more likely to fight than females. Among*** 
  feral cats, the most common reason for cat fighting is competition between*** 
  two males to mate with a female. In such cases, most fights*** 
  are won by the heavier male. Another common reason for fighting in*** ...
  )